# Go error: unexpected Nul in input

Tags: go

I just installed the go.msi in C:/Go.
And I set my Path(C:\Go\bin) and GOPATH(E:\code\go).But when I try to run "go run test.go" I get the following error:  test.go:2:8: read C:\Go\src\fmt\export_test.go: unexpected NUL in input
package main
        imports runtime: read C:\Go\src\runtime\export_unix_test.go: unexpected NUL in input

I can not open these files.
The code i have is:

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main()  {
        fmt.Println("Something")
    }
```

The path of the test.go file is E:\code\go\test.go
When i run go env i get:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=E:\code\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
```

the output of go version is:
    go version go1.9.2 windows/amd64

Comment: What is the output of `go env` and `go version` commands? Also in what folder is the test code above? And in what folder you run `go run test.go`?

Comment: Please change to UTF-8 from Unicode, and see if it works

Comment: I'm with @Apolozeus on this: if you used Notepad to create your quick sample, it could save it as "Unicode", and that means UTF-16LE on Windows while Go explicitly defines that its source code files must be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: I used Vs code to create it. It says UTF-8.

Comment: This is an cryptic error message for having the wrong file encoding. Thanks for clarifying it needs UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some things in your `GOPATH`. You need a folder structure like the following:

```
E:\code\go\src\{repository}\{package}\gofile.go
```

So for this, you could have it be:

```
E:\code\go\src\local-only\testing\test.go
```

Comment: That structure is only needed when you intend to import any packages (located under `{workspace}/pkg`). A dumb `go run` call such as the one made by OP can be done from anywhere.

Comment: I found out that the {packege}(testing) is not  necessary. Without it i ran the code

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem with **golang 1.10.0** on **Windows 10**:
When creating the file to run with `echo "my go program" > myProgram.go` the wrong encoding was generated: **UCS-2 LE BOM**.

Converting to **UTF-8** resolved the *NUL in input*.

Looks like it's ***PowerShell*** that encodes in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) by default ([windows system locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-international-core-systemlocale)), with ***CMD*** and ***PowerShell Core*** this problem should not happen.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. 
Turns out powershell encodes in Windows-1252 by default ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 ).

I don't know what side effects changing this default for powershell will do, so I just changed the default console in VS Code to cmd. 
Creating the files with echo my text here > myFunc.go in cmd works as expected.

Comment: I took some time to add your comment in my answer @EmanuelLindström thanks again

Comment: Woah, weird issue, I used PS and `"" > main.go` and it really did create UTF-16, did not notice that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on the web I read "The problem is that somewhere in your 'main.go' is a ASCII NULL character."  To get past it:

1. Copy all the code from 'main.go' into Notepad and save it
2. Delete 'main.go'
3. Create blank 'main.go'
4. Paste code from Notepad into 'main.go'
5. Run: go run .    => Success

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just ran into this issue and solved it by running `chkdsk /f` from `cmd.exe` with administrative rights. (The command should be run against the drive Go is installed)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe how this most silliest thing couldn't be debugged from the when that topic opened to that year. When you create .go files with windows's "echo" command because of that command creates files with another character encoding than utf-8 gives that most annoying silliest error. It's really frustrating when you work with golang. Shame on all golang team.

If you created .go and/or .html files(i don't try .css or .js files but probably they'll cause to throw same error) with windows's echo command you'll take that error, to fix this you need to delete that file first and recreate your .go file with your mouse.